# how to prove a set is a closed half space: here is the condition

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let A be a closed convex set  and the complement of A is convex. prove that A is a closed half space.
I guess it's like proving half space belongs to A and A belongs to halfspace,
the latter is obvious, so how to prove the former.
when assume not, how to use the property of convex~~
Thanks~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note, that this is only true if both $A$ and $X \setminus A$ are non empty (otherwise $A = \emptyset$, $X$ are also possible).

Let's start with finding the hyperplane bounding the space in question. Let's denote the topological vector space we are working in with $X$. As $A$ and $X \setminus A$ are convex, and $X \setminus A$ is open, there is - by the Hahn-Banach seperation thereom - an $x^* \in X^*$ and an $\alpha \in \mathbf R$, such that
$$ \tag 1 \Re x^*(a) \le \alpha < \Re x^*(b), \qquad \text{all } a \in A, b \in X\setminus A $$
Hence, $A \subseteq \{\Re x^* \le \alpha\}$, and $X\setminus A \subseteq \{\Re x^* > \alpha\}$. The latter implies $$A \supseteq X \setminus \{\Re x^* > \alpha\} = \{\Re x^* \le \alpha \}$$
Hence, $A = \{\Re x^* \le \alpha\}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think the last second line you were trying to say: {Rx∗≤α}⊆A, but I got it anyway~~~